# Azure Sql Database - how do you determine the app service name from the database logs?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We're having some issues with Azure Sql Databases, and their host name from sp_who reports back something like 'RD000xxxxxxx' for the hostname.

How can you determine the app service that is connecting to the database from this hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it, but not through the management api or the portals.

https://[your-app-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/Env

It's under Machine Name.

Comment: Is there a place I can insert the hostname, and then backtrack to which application name it is?

Answer (score 1):

RD000* is the VM hostname if not set explicitly. If you have the access to your deployments, you may be able to check it using APIs (or in case of VM RDP for example). If you suspect that it is not from your deployment, then, i strongly suspect, there is no way to detect who is it (perhaps, technical support may, but i doubt). With some possibility, it will change as well.